# PHP e-mail reminder when the date and time is reached

Tags: php, cron

I am making a to-do script which will take description, time ,date from the user and msg_id is auto-incremented.
It is then stored in a table called reminders.
Now what I cannot understand is how can I make it **work at that particular time** ? 
I can make it work on that day by setting a *cronjob* that runs everyday and executes a script which checks if the day is equal to current date ,if it is, it will a mail to the user.
 But setting the *cronjob* to work every minute , I think it will increase the server usage way up .

 Any other solution that won't increase the server usage way high would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time

Comment: `"But setting the cronjob to work every minute , I think it will increase the server usage way up"` - Not if the script is efficient.  Running something once per minute is _very_ light work for a computer.

Comment: Usual solution to this problem is cron or server daemon, it depends on your usage of this feature

Comment: I am on a $9/month hosting, wouldn't my host get angry with me for using well, more than I paid for ?

Comment: If your hoster complains, then don't support down-to-the-minute scheduling. Reduce to 10 minute intervals and you cut the server load by a factor of 10, because you'll only run the script one tenth of the time.

Comment: Aah! Why didn't I think of that, that would be cool. I can't accept a comment otherwise I would have. Thanks everybody.